# Command of f2 Addon

Tags: python

I have a question for my Piemenu code Project:

I want to implement the command of the f2 Addon, which is already built in Blender, but I don't get how to write the code for that command, because I have only less experience.

[image: code, already tried]

Comment: What command are you trying to pull from within your pie menu script? I am only aware of pressing 'F' to form a face from a selected edge and its neighboring edges. Calling a pie menu to do what a single key press does seems like extra steps.

Comment: I'm making a piemenu-set for my space mouse, which has only 4 button's to press. But I want it as an alternative fur my keyboard. So what I want to have: the same Effekt when I press f on my keyboard on a piemenu-set,which I can call with one of these 4 Button's, and yes I also think that needs some extras to to, but maybe I already have an idea. Take the F2 add-on code in my menu code and than define as key a viriable which I bind in my menu, but I think that's a bad and difficult solution and I hoped there will be something less difficult...

Comment: All you have to do is to map the F2 operator that is mapped to the 'F' key to your button then, but I don't have any experience with the space mouse, and I don't know how you go about that. You might see if you can just go to the input section of your keymap in userprefs and see if you can replace the 'F' key in that operator to the button on the mouse....

Comment: hm I try if I get that, the alle special at the spacemouse is that the key's to start something are named NDOF_BUTTON_... that's the difference, everything else is the same. And I Using Pie menus, because there are to less buttons to set every bottun on function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so complicated than I thought...

To use the f2 Addon in my Pie-menu, all I need is:

```
pie.operator("mesh.f2", text="Make Face (F2)", icon="FACESEL" )
```

and the text and icon is optinonal.

Thanks @Craig D Jones